# Opposite of read-from-string clisp

Tags: common-lisp, reverse, clisp

I would like to define a function `to-string` that does the opposite of the following.

```
> (read-from-string "(foo a b)")
(FOO A B) ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functions [`write-to-string` and `prin1-to-string`](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_write-to-_nc-to-string.html) do what you want:

```
> (read-from-string "(foo \"Hi\" 17)")
(FOO "Hi" 17) ;

> (prin1-to-string '(FOO "Hi" 17))
"(FOO \"Hi\" 17)"
> (write-to-string '(FOO "Hi" 17))
"(FOO \"Hi\" 17)"
```

The function `write-to-string` additionally takes keyword arguments that allow you to adjust the result:

```
> (write-to-string '(FOO "Hi" 17) :case :downcase)
"(foo \"Hi\" 17)"
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work

```
(with-output-to-string (s)
  (princ '(1 2 3) s))
```

Comment: Note that `princ` omits escape characters; therefore watch out if your object contains strings for example.